# .empty() jQuery method and undefined value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div id="errorsum"></div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
 var errornbr = 0;
 var mess;
 $("#addclient  input.form-control").each(function (index) {
     if ($(this).val() == "") {
         if ($(this).attr("data-val") != undefined) {
             if ($(this).attr("data-val-required") != undefined) {
                 errornbr = errornbr + 1;
                 mess = mess + "<br/>" + $(this).attr("data-val-required");
             }
         }
     }
 });
 $("#errorsum").empty();
 if (errornbr > 0) {
     $("#errorsum").append("<label class='col-xs-3 control-label text-danger' >" + mess + "</label>");
 }
```

First line of the label text is always `undefined`. the `mess` didn't contains such value.

So I need to know:

1. Does the `empty()` method is the reason of this?
2. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: change `var mess;` to `var mess = '';`

Comment: @guradio thank you very much, plz post your comment as an answer

Comment: Why not append to current value? `mess += "<br/>" + $(t.......`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `var mess;` to `var mess = ''`;

Make the assume text value making it not return undefined

Answer (score 0):

Please use ( typeof VALUE != 'undefined' ) instead of ( VALUE != undefined )

Please write condition like this

if( typeof $(this).attr("data-val") != 'undefined' ){

```
 if( typeof $(this).attr("data-val-required") != 'undefined' ){

 }
```

}